# Is struct { } x; an anonymous struct?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013, clang, compiler-warnings

Clang, GCC and Visual Studio 2013 complain about this piece of code.

```
struct { };
```

Clang with `-Weverything`:

> warning: anonymous structs are a GNU extension
>   `[-Wgnu-anonymous-struct]`

GCC with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`:

> warning: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs `[-Wpedantic]`

Visual Studio 2013 with `/W4`:

> warning [C4094](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y0f9tby.aspx): untagged 'struct' declared no symbols

As soon as I add a variable declaration, the warnings disappear.

```
struct { } x;
```

And all three complain about an unused variable.

I assume this is still an anonymous struct and illegal C++ and that the compilers stop warning for some reason. But since the behavior persists in three separate compilers, I wanted to know if adding a variable declaration somehow changes the semantics of the program.

---

If this is an illegal program, `-pedantic-errors` doesn't cause either Clang or GCC to result in a compilation error. Similarly for Visual Studio, `/Za` should force a compilation error but it doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is clear if you add fields to the struct.

```
struct A {
    // Anonymous struct
    struct {
        int x;
    };
};

struct B {
    // Not an anonymous struct
    struct {
        int x;
    } y;
};
```

With the anonymous struct, you can access the `x` field of `A a` by writing `a.x`.

With the named struct, you have to access `x` of `B b` by writing `b.y.x`.

Anonymous structs are part of the C11 standard, and they are a common extension available in various compilers including both GCC and MSVC.  Since they are nonstandard in C++, enabling pedantic warnings will trigger diagnostics.  This is exactly what pedantic warnings are designed to accomplish.

### Anonymous ≠ unnamed (what are anonymous structs?)

A structure declaration can also declare a variable.  The structure's name is called the "tag".  Omitting *both* creates an anonymous structure.

(Note: These examples are illustrative.  They are not complete or correct pieces of code.)

```
// Structure tag is "A", declares a variable named "x".
struct A { int field; } x;
x.field = 7;
A y;
y.field = 8;

// Structure tag is "B", no variables declared.
struct B { int field; };
B x;
x.field = 10;

// Structure has no tag, declares a variable named "y".
struct { int field; } y;
y.field = 12;

// Structure has no tag and declares no variable...
// therefore, it is an "anonymous struct".
// The contents are accessible from "outside" the structure.
struct { int field; };
field = 10;
```

In MSVC, you can also create an anonymous structure the following way, but this is nonstandard (GCC supports this via `-fms-extensions`):

```
struct A { int x };
struct B { struct A; int y; };
// B has two fields, x and y.
```

The definition for "anonymous struct" is given in N1570 §6.7.2.1 paragraph 13,

> An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier with no tag is called an *anonymous structure*…

Comment: Yet, no options will force a compilation error for `struct {} x;`.

Comment: @user4393124 There's nothing wrong with `struct {} x`.

Comment: `"anonymous struct"` doesn't compile for me with either gcc4.9 and clang3.6, using standards c11 or c++11.

Comment: @HongxuChen: It needs to be a member of a structure, it can't be a local or global variable.

Answer (score 1):

`struct { } x;` is an `unnamed` struct.

see an example for antonymous structure:

```
struct phone
{
    long number;
};

struct person
{
    char   name[30];
    char   gender;
    struct phone;    // Anonymous structure; no name needed
} Jim;
```

Comment: The terminology here is incorrect... `struct { } x;` is not an anonymous struct.  See N1570 §6.7.2.1 ¶13 for a definition of *anonymous structure*: "An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier with no tag is called an anonymous structure."  Note that anonymous structures are absent from the C++ specification, this is from the C spec.